# Recursively search an entire directory for last accessed time on files

Tags: linux, bash

I recently inherited a Linux webserver that the previous admin used to basically dump any and everything into. What I would like to do is get a list of all files in the directory sorted by their last accessed time with the intention of wiping out anything that is not being used at all by the company.

I'm assuming I should probably just go back 3 months as the company is very active with their web services so anything that hasn't been touched at all in the past 3 months is most likely dead weight.

I tried using the answers in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566310/how-to-recursively-find-and-list-the-latest-modified-files-in-a-directory-with-s

But it didn't seem to work well.

As a caveat, my Linux admin experience is very junior. I am well versed in deployment and configuration but I've never had to do something like this (I mean, this thing is a real mess and it sorely needs it).

I'm not against putting together a PHP script to run it but, again, I'm not that hot with PHP either so I really need some straightforward help here. Ideally, having a script to run that will also have a delete file option would make my day, or even a BASH command sequence that can have rm included if I decide everything it finds is junk.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds right up [find's](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) alley:

```
$ cd $ROOT_OF_JUNKYARD
$ find . -atime 90
```

Should list all the files accessed within the last 90 days.

*NOTE*: Keeping track of the `atime` attribute is somewhat costly for the file system, so some administrators turn it off, for file systems that support doing so (ext2 on Linux does). If your machine is configured to not maintain `atime`, this approach won't work. :|

Once you're happy all the files listed are junk, you can trivially extend the command to delete the results:

```
$ find . -mtime 90 -exec rm -i \{\} \;
```

The `-i` option to `rm` makes it *interactive*, it will prompt you to make sure about every removal. This is to protect you from blowing your foot off, which is otherwise quite easy with recursively applied `rm` commands.

Comment: @undwind you are talking to a linux newbie... He'll end up deleting a good chunk from his home directory if he was to follow you verbatim without paying attention.

Comment: @Ahmed: That's a good point, I added the `-i` option to `rm` to make it slightly safer.

Comment: I think mtime isn't going to help. It can't be the modified time as these are files that have been written a while back but are still in use. It has to be an accessed time. I'm assuming using atime instead of mtime would suit that requirement? Yes?

Comment: @MT_Mike: I think so, yes, I edited the answer.

Comment: @unwind hehe +1 for -i but you forgot to update the second line to `-atime` :)

Comment: Interesting, I'm going to assume the atime function is disabled as that returned no data at all.

Running mtime only returned a few files, which is insanely inaccurate.

Would a daily backup impact the mtime stamp?

Comment: Note that the `.` is not mandatory: if no directory is specified, `find` operates from the current directory by default.

Comment: @fge . is not mandatory for the GNU version of find only ... :-) i put it there for completeness

Answer (score 2):

First things first :) back up everything!

For purpose of this example i'll assume your files are in `/var/www` change that to whatever it ACTUALLY is on your system.

```
    tar fcvz www-backup.tar.gz /var/www
```

will create a back up of your existing web environment in a tar file (in case things go wrong you can always retrieve missing files)

Now to find files that have not been accessed in 90 days or so:

```
    cd /var/www
    find . -atime 90 -type f -ls
```

Lists the files on screen with modified times.. this way you can make sure that the files that you are trying to delete are INDEED the files that you WANT to delete.  You can pipe that to less so that you can scroll up and down:

```
   find . -atime 90 -type f -ls | less
```

use up and down arrows to view the list, quit type 'q'.

If everything looks okay:

```
    pwd
```

make sure you are still in the right working directory.

```
    find . -atime 90 -type f echo rm -f {}  \; > doit.sh
```

this will create a file called doit.sh which will actually contain the removal commands.

Read it once more:

```
    less doit.sh
```

if all the files look okay for removal then you can run it:

```
    sh doit.sh
```